# Does there exists $k\in(0,\infty)$ s.t. $A^*A-I-kH_A>0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given fixed $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, I want to check whether there exists some $k\in(0,\infty)$ such that

$$A^*A-I-kH_A>0,$$

where $H_A=(A+A^*)/2$ and $I$ is an identity matrix.

---

Let $A_1=A^*A-I$ and $A_2=H_A$, then we have $A_1-kA_2>0$. Then I think we need to check whether eigenvalues of $A_1-kA_2$ are larger than $0$ for some $k\in(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a >0$. If $A=aI$ then your inequality says $a^{2}I-I-kaI >0$ which does not hold for any $k >0$ if $a<1$.

Comment: I know that it doesn't hold for all $A$, but if someone gives me fixed matrix $A$, I want to check if there exists some $k$ such that inequality holds

Comment: @Lee I have given an example where no $k>0$ works. You can take $a=\frac 1 2$ in my example.

Comment: ok, so if $A$ is diagonal with diagonal elements all equal to $a$, then there exists $k>0$ such that inequality holds if and only if $a>1$. What about the other cases, when diagonal elements are not all equal or when $A$ is not diagonal matrix

Comment: You are changing the question now. My answer is complete for the present question. If you want to ask for what matrices $A$ such a  number $k$ exists you could ask a separate question. @Lee

Comment: ok, thank for your help, I will post new question.